# Keeping a log file related to a media files usage

Tags: c#, media, detect, playback, alarm

I would like detect and act when a spesific mp3 file is used(played as an alarm in another application) in c#.

Waiting for ideas,
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not update the lastaccesstime when a file is opened for reading, so that cannot be used.

There are two ways I can think of doing this, but both involving polling the system.

1. Loop every X seconds and try to open the file for write. If this fails then the file is open.
2. Loop every X seconds and use a WMI Query to see if the file is in use.

Either way, you will then have to handle consecutive "opens" within a certain period of  time count as only a single instance.

Comment: in that matter, i should change the default alarm file with a x+1 second long void file, than i wouldn't skip any occurances...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the File.LastAccessTime method.

Details Here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime.aspx

Essentially use a loop that peroidically checks.

The problem with this solution is that, from MSDN documentation, "This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the operating system."

Comment: thanks, this might be considered as one option, but i need a robust solution in order to act, this one might fail,a lot.

Comment: It might be your best solution because Windows does not always update the value. The probably guaranteed way is to hook right before a read from the file system (possbility unknown).

Comment: tested it out, looks like lastAcessTime feature is not going to work at all. But anyways, thanks alot for your idea.